# Ask R question with a reproducible example

Tags: feature-request

Questions in [r](/questions/tagged/r) are mostly dealing with data.
We need usually a **reproducible example**.

But many R/Stack Overflow newbie don't know how to use some tricks like dput(), dump() or structure() to reproduce their data.

Can you add at right in the **How to Ask list** for example a mention to this tricks when the asker add an R tag for example? or add a link to this :
[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Consider having that bit of the tag excerpt first, not the spiel about what it is, as they should already know what it is they're tagging

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's ever necessary to add tag-specific tips to How to Ask. Most questions involving specific programming problems need reproducible examples. This isn't unique to R.

Maybe the current prose can be clarified or expanded, saying for problems that you need help debugging you ought to provide a reproducible example so we can analyze the code first-hand, but having it display just for a specific tag doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: yes all questions need a reproducible example, but here my concern is about manipulating **data**. The use of tag is just a suggestion (the first Idea I have).